# Validating input and checking if it's in a range

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation

```
print("What would you like to do:\n1. Enter new information\n2. House- 
based statsitics\n3. Specific Criteria statistics")

while True:
  try:
    option = input("Enter 1 2 or 3: ")
  except ValueError:
    option = input("Enter 1 2 or 3: ")

  if option < 1 and option > 3:
    option = input("Enter 1 2 or 3: ")
  else:
     break

print(option)
```

I'm trying to make sure my input is between 1 to 3, when I do this I'll get a TypeError, but if I change it to `int(option = input("Enter 1 2 or 3: "))` it will return an error if a string is entered.

Comment: `if option < 1 and option > 3:` can never be true. A number can't be less than 1 and greater than 3 at the same time. Also, `input` _always_ returns a string, you need to convert it to int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) to check if input is in specified range:

```
print("What would you like to do:\n1. Enter new information\n2. House- based statsitics\n3. Specific Criteria statistics")

while True:
  try:
    option = int(input("Enter 1 2 or 3: "))
  except ValueError:
    option = int(input("Enter 1 2 or 3: "))

  if option in range(1, 4):
    break

print(option)
```

**Sample run**:

```
What would you like to do:
1. Enter new information                                    
2. House- based statsitics                                  
3. Specific Criteria statistics                              
Enter 1 2 or 3: 0                                           
Enter 1 2 or 3: 4                                           
Enter 1 2 or 3: a                                           
Enter 1 2 or 3: 2                                           
2
```

Comment: That worked, I just needed to change the range to (1, 4)

Answer (score 2):

or just that:

```
option = None
while option not in {'1', '2', '3'}:  # or:  while option not in set('123')
    option = input("Enter 1 2 or 3: ")
option = int(option)
```

with the restriction to the 3 strings `'1', '2', '3'` there is not even the need to catch a `ValueError` when casting to an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def func():

    option = int(input("enter input"))
    if not abs(option) in range(1,4):
        print('Wrong')
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print("Correct")
        func()
func()
```

Comment: And if the user enters 0?

Comment: Also, this does not ask for repeated input

Comment: is there any restriction for your repeted iteration ?(how many iteration)

Comment: The question should be enclosed in a while loop. Why do you call the function from within itself on success?

Comment: this will also accept `-2`. and what is the recursion for? you will be stuck asking the user input forever (or until the recursion limit is reached); the program should go on and so something with it.